# Changing a request url based on url when using ui.route

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-http

I am using `$http` in angular for `ajax` calls and using `ui.router` for `routing`.

**Routes**

```
.state("/dashboard.inactive", {
  url: "/inactive",
  templateUrl: "angular/templates/dashboard/inactive.html",
  controller: "dashboardCtrl"
})
.state("/dashboard.drafts", {
  url: "/drafts",
  templateUrl: "angular/templates/dashboard/drafts.html",
  controller: "dashboardCtrl"
});
```

So the below code works if it is for a single URL.

**Controller**

```
app.controller('dashboardCtrl', function ($scope, DashboardFactory){
    DashboardFactory.listings(function(DashboardFactory) {
        $scope.results = DashboardFactory;
    });
});
```

Below factory is fetching only from `drafts.json` resource. So when the URL changes to inactive I want it to fetch from `inactive.json` and `active.json` respectively.

**Factory**

```
app.factory('DashboardFactory', function($http){
    return {
        listings: function(callback){
            $http.get('drafts.json').success(callback);
        }
    };

});
```

In short I need to send requests to any one of the below 3 URLs based on the URL

```
1) '/drafts.json'
2) '/inactive.json'
3) '/active.json'
```

I can create a different controllers for each active, inactive and drafts and make it fetch as expected. But is there any better way to do this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [$state](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state) service of ui route in order to tell which state your are in.
Just inject $state to your service and then use `$state.current` in order to access the current state config.

```
app.factory('DashboardFactory',
     function($http, $state){ 
       return { 
          listings: function(callback){ 
              var currentView = $state.current.url.replace('/', '');
              $http.get(currentView + '.json').success(callback); 
          } 
       }; 
    });
```

A better solution would be to either use the `params` property of the `state` config or add some custom property like:

```
.state("/dashboard.inactive", {
  url: "/inactive",
  templateUrl: "angular/templates/dashboard/inactive.html",
  controller: "dashboardCtrl",
  params: {
    json: 'inactive.json'
  }
})
.state("/dashboard.drafts", {
  url: "/drafts",
  templateUrl: "angular/templates/dashboard/drafts.html",
  controller: "dashboardCtrl",
  params: {
    json: 'drafts.json'
  }
});
```

It is described in the [documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state).

Comment: Thanks. The first solution works. But I think the second one is more elegant. But how can I reference the params in the factory?  Also the documentation link is not working

Comment: I've fixed the link to the docs.  You inject the $state as I've shown and can reference the config object, in which you can add the params property (or any other property) and then it is available via the `$state.current`.

Comment: just one doubt..Isn't this approach bad as it prevents caching from happening as the same variable is reassigned with different results or am I wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by caching? Caching of the response to the ajax calls?

Comment: I don't believe it has something to do with the ajax call itself but more of a server setting of what to cache and what not to cache. Also, I think that the browser caches static pages.